# How would I enable users to download an excel file which is created on the server

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

I am able to create the excel file using apache poi but how would I enable the users to download the excel file which would be created on the server?

```
public String export(UserDetails user) throws Exception {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    List<UserDetails> lstUserDetail = getUserDetailList();

    for (short RowNum=1; RowNum<lstUserDetail.size();RowNum++){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
        UserDetails userDetail = lstUserDetail.get(RowNum);

        HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell((short)0);
        HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell((short)1);
        HSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell((short)2);
        HSSFCell cell4 = row.createCell((short)3);

        cell2.setCellValue(userDetail.getStrUserName());
        cell3.setCellValue(userDetail.getStrEMail());
        cell4.setCellValue(userDetail.getStrUserPhone());
        cell5.setCellValue(userDetail.getStrUserAddress());
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("E:\\workbook.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below where you will make a call to FileDownload servlet once user click on download link

```
public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String filename = "E:\\workbook.xls";


        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + filename);

        int octet;
        while((octet = in.read()) != -1)
            out.write(octet);

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: but when the code would be deployed on the server,i would not know the location of the file...."E:\\workbook.xls"   is my location on my harddisk...how do i go about if i do not know the location of the created file.??